# Regex not working in class but works in execute anonymous

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

You can get some context here on my [previous](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399812/regex-for-case-number-south-african-id-and-passport/399827) post.

When I run the below code on execute anonymous, it renders the following result:

```
String txt = 'Requesting service for Id Number 9202204720082, Case C - 12246503 and passport A01524783';
String regex = '[ADMT]\\d{8}|\\d{2}[01]\\d[0-3]\\d ?\\d{4} ?[01]8 ?\\d|(?i)C - \\d{8}';
System.debug('========' + regex);
Matcher thematcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(txt);
String idno = (thematcher.find()) ? thematcher.group() : '';
System.debug('========= ' + idno);
```

[image]

When I call the class from execute anonymous:

```
String txt = 'Requesting service for Id Number 9202204720082';
String regex = '[ADMT]\\d{8}|\\d{2}[01]\\d[0-3]\\d ?\\d{4} ?[01]8 ?\\d|(?i)C - \\d{8}';
System.debug('========' + new EmailLinker(new Messaging.InboundEmail()).findMatch(txt, regex));
```

[image]

If I call the class directly from the backend:

```
public String findMatch(
    String emailContent,
    String criteriaValue
) {
    String idNumber = '';
    criteriaValue = criteriaValue.unescapeHtml4();
    System.debug('======== Criteria ' + criteriaValue);
    System.debug('======== content ' + emailContent);
    Matcher emailMatcher = Pattern.compile(criteriaValue).matcher(emailContent);
    System.debug('======== email match ' + emailMatcher.find());
    Boolean isFound = Boolean.valueOf(emailMatcher.find());
    //if (isFound == true) {
        System.debug('======== ID ' + emailMatcher.group());
        idNumber = emailMatcher.group();
    //}
    System.debug('======== ID ' + idNumber);
    return idNumber;
}
```

[image]

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** As per the comment

```
public String findMatch(
        String emailContent,
        String criteriaValue
    ) {
        String idNumber = '';
        criteriaValue = criteriaValue.unescapeHtml4();
        System.debug('======== Criteria ' + criteriaValue);// [ADMT]\\d{8}|\\d{2}[01]\\d[0-3]\\d ?\\d{4} ?[01]8 ?\\d|(?i)C - \\d{8}
        System.debug('======== content ' + emailContent);
        Matcher emailMatcher = Pattern.compile(criteriaValue).matcher(emailContent);
        if (emailMatcher.find()) {
            System.debug('======== ID ' + emailMatcher.group());
            idNumber = emailMatcher.group();
        }
        System.debug('======== ID ' + idNumber);
        return idNumber;
    }
```

This is still not working, it only works when I hardcode the regex pattern, and can't do that as it is dynamic.

Comment: remove your `System.debug('======== email match ' + emailMatcher.find());`  line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to doc

> find()
> **Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. This method returns true if a subsequence of the input sequence matches this Matcher object's pattern.**

hence if you call `find()` twice, one from `Systm.debug` another from code., it will try to find next to next sequence, which will fail.

Thus removing `Boolean isFound = Boolean.valueOf(emailMatcher.find());` from code should work fine.

I replicated your scenario like this:

```
public with sharing class EmailLinker {

    public String findMatch(
            String emailContent,
            String criteriaValue) {
        String idNumber = '';
        criteriaValue = criteriaValue.unescapeHtml4();
        System.debug('======== Criteria ' + criteriaValue);
        System.debug('======== content ' + emailContent);
        Matcher emailMatcher = Pattern.compile(criteriaValue).matcher(emailContent);
        System.debug('======== email match ' + emailMatcher.find());

        //if (isFound == true) {
        System.debug('======== ID ' + emailMatcher.group());
        idNumber = emailMatcher.group();
        //}
        System.debug('======== ID ' + idNumber);
        return idNumber;
    }

}
```

Anonymouos apex :

```
String txt = 'Requesting service for Id Number 9202204720082';
String regex = '[ADMT]\\d{8}|\\d{2}[01]\\d[0-3]\\d ?\\d{4} ?[01]8 ?\\d|(?i)C - \\d{8}';
System.debug('========' + new EmailLinker().findMatch(txt, regex));
```

Shows:

> 16:29:00.168 (179827998)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|======== Criteria [ADMT]\d{8}|\d{2}[01]\d[0-3]\d ?\d{4} ?[01]8 ?\d|(?i)C - \d{8}
> 16:29:00.168 (179898844)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|======== content Requesting service for Id Number 9202204720082
> 16:29:00.168 (184007884)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|======== email match true
> 16:29:00.168 (184074021)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|======== ID 9202204720082
> 16:29:00.168 (184103751)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|======== ID 9202204720082
> 16:29:00.168 (184134185)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|========9202204720082

Comment: That is helpful, thanks! But if you call the EmaiLinker class from a trigger or another piece of automation it won't work. In my case it is not working from a backend call i.e. I'm calling the EmailLinker class from an InboundEmailService class. From exec anon it does work, but not from apex class.

Comment: It will work, try removing one of the `find` methods and keep only one.

Comment: It doesn't work - I will add my code as an edit to the question so that you can view it.

Comment: @d_k When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean, still getting the exception?

Comment: No,  emailMatcher.group() returns nothing. It only works when the regex is hardcoded.

Comment: ok so your first error got resolved, where exception was being thrown. You may have to show now how are you passing regex dynamically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144861/discussion-between-d-k-and-nagendra-singh).

Answer (score 1):

The Apex compiler requires certain characters to be escaped in order to work. This is mentioned in [Primitive Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm):

> EscapeSequences: All Strings in Apex use the same escape sequences as SOQL strings: \b (backspace), \t (tab), \n (line feed), \f (form feed), \r (carriage return), " (double quote), ' (single quote), and \ (backslash).

Further, regular expressions also use \ for its own escape sequences.

Subsequently, this means that you need to escape any \ that you want to put into your Apex source code to get them to the regular expression engine.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\bHello\\b');
```

Matches the full word `Hello` (`\b` is the word-border matching pattern in regular expressions).

When your data comes from another place other than Apex source code, you don't need to escape it. This includes reading from a field, a static resource, an email body, and so on. The extra escape sequence is only for Apex source code.